# Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I have a long select statement below, and I receive the error data too long on my Node server when I run it, but when I copy paste it into MySQL Workbench it works fine.  How can I go about troubleshooting this problem?

```
SELECT `199_roster`.`first`, `199_roster`.`last`, `199_roster`.`gender`, `199_roster`.`grade`, `199_results`.`ath_id`, `199_results`.`place`, `199_results`.`date`, `199_results`.`comment`, `199_results`.`100m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`110m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`100m Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`100m Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`1600m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`1600m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`4x100m Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`4x100m Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`400m Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`400m Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`200m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`200m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`800m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`800m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`200m Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`200m Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`4x400m Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`4x400m Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`High Jump (F)`, `199_results`.`High Jump (M)`, `199_results`.`Long Jump (F)`, `199_results`.`Long Jump (M)`, `199_results`.`Shot Put (F)`, `199_results`.`Shot Put (M)`, `199_results`.`Discus (F)`, `199_results`.`Discus (M)`, `199_results`.`Pole Vault (F)`, `199_results`.`Pole Vault (M)`, `199_results`.`3200m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`3200m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`300m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`300m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`4x800m Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`4x800m Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`100m Hurd. Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`110m Hurd. Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`100m Dash Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`100m Dash Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`200m Dash Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`200m Dash Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`400m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`400m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`2000m Steeplechase (F)`, `199_results`.`2000m Steeplechase (M)`, `199_results`.`3000m Steeplechase (F)`, `199_results`.`3000m Steeplechase (M)`, `199_results`.`1500m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`1500m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`3000m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`3000m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`5000m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`5000m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`10000m Run (F)`, `199_results`.`10000m Run (M)`, `199_results`.`Triple Jump (F)`, `199_results`.`Triple Jump (M)`, `199_results`.`Hammer Throw (F)`, `199_results`.`Hammer Throw (M)`, `199_results`.`Javelin Throw (F)`, `199_results`.`Javelin Throw (M)`, `199_results`.`Distance Medley Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`Distance Medley Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`Sprint Medley Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`Sprint Medley Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`4x200m Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`4x200m Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`4x1500m Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`4x1500m Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`4x1600m Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`4x1600m Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`Shuttle Hurdle Relay (F)`, `199_results`.`Shuttle Hurdle Relay (M)`, `199_results`.`60m Dash Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`60m Dash Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`60m Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`60m Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`60m Hurd. Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`60m Hurd. Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`60m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`60m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`50m Dash Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`50m Dash Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`50m Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`50m Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`50m Hurd. Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`50m Hurd. Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`50m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`50m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`55m Dash Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`55m Dash Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`55m Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`55m Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`55m Hurd. Trial (F)`, `199_results`.`55m Hurd. Trial (M)`, `199_results`.`55m Hurdles (F)`, `199_results`.`55m Hurdles (M)`, `199_results`.`100y Dash (F)`, `199_results`.`100y Dash (M)`, `199_results`.`Mile Run (F)`, `199_results`.`Mile Run (M)` FROM `199_results` INNER JOIN `199_roster` ON `199_roster`.`ath_id` = `199_results`.`ath_id` WHERE `199_results`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:01' AND '2018-05-08 23:59:59';
```

Here is the portion of my .js file where I make the query. (Normally I create the query on the client side and send it dynamically, but for debugging I have the variable set as below)

```
var fullQuery = "SELECT * FROM  `199_results` INNER JOIN `199_roster` ON `199_roster`.`ath_id` = `199_results`.`ath_id` WHERE `199_results`.`date` BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:01' AND '2018-05-08 23:59:59';"

    const db = require("../db"); 
    db.query(fullQuery, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) { 
            res.render("results", { 
                title: "Results",
                mysqlError: err.message
                })
            return console.error('stupid error', err)
        } else {
            req.session.results = rows;
            res.send(rows)
        }
    })
```

Here is more in the error message if it helps:

> Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol          /sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Q          uery.js:77:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protoco          l.js:279:23)
>       at Parser.write (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39          :16)
>       at Socket. (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:2          8)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
>       --------------------
>       at Pool.query (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
>       at MySQLStore.set (/root/site/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:19          9:19)
>       at Session.save (/root/site/node_modules/express-session/session/session.js:          72:25)
>       at Session.save (/root/site/node_modules/express-session/index.js:381:15)
>       at ServerResponse.end (/root/site/node_modules/express-session/index.js:330:          21)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/root/site/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:          10)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/root/site/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:          15)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/root/site/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:          21)
>       at Query.db.query [as _callback] (/root/site/routes/resultsRouter.js:184:9)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (/root/site/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/          Sequence.js:88:24)

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's *this* query?  That error typically accompanies an insert or update query, and implies that you are trying to insert a value that is too long into a columm *named* `data`.  If it has another meaning, I'm unaware of it.

Comment: I was confused by this also, because I can't find any select statements with this error when searching online everywhere.  I've edited my question to show how I'm sending the query, so I'm pretty sure it's what is being sent.

Comment: I can't think of a specific mechanism but I wonder if this could have anything to do with differing `max_allowed_packet` values between node and workbench.  It shouldn't, but absent another idea, that's where my mind goes, next.  Neither of these tables is a view, is it?

Comment: I increased the max_allowed_packet size from 2m to 16m, the data is really small so I don't think that was it, but worth a shot.  Would having 105 columns in the table be contributing to this problem?  Most are my columns are varchar < 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a Node async issue it seems (I should have realized this way sooner).

By commenting out

```
else {
        //req.session.results = rows;
        res.send(rows)
}
```

everything is working perfectly now, no errors, everything displaying correctly.  [michael-sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) was correct in seeing that it wasn't a query error of sorts, I'll up vote if I ever have enough rep to do so.

Comment: I've had the same issue. `req.session.import_result = result;` was source of the error, not any query made before

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving so much data, can you not just do

```
SELECT * FROM   FROM `199_results` INNER JOIN `199_roster` ON 
`199_roster`.`ath_id` = `199_results`.`ath_id` WHERE `199_results`.`date` 
BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:01' AND '2018-05-08 23:59:59';
```

Comment: The query you provided is more elegant and works in MySQL Workbench, but not on the server.  I receive the same error, data too long.